# Watson Virtual Agent bot-id doesn't appear

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to test the Watson Virtual Agent but I can't find the bot-id in the page

> https://developer.ibm.com/api/view/id-339#id7930

I got to new dialog but I did not find the USE button, is there any other way to get my bot-id?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For see your `bot_id` you need to access the Watson Virtual agent and click on the "Documentation" link.

After it, you can see a lot of good information for built your application.

This image will help you more:

[image]

The link for your access:

[image]

Obs.: As you can see in the [official API Reference](https://developer.ibm.com/api/view/id-339#doc), you must always send your `bot_id` for every request.

- See the Official Documentation [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/virtual-agent/index.html#about).

Comment: thanks for your answer I have found the bot-id with the reference of the last screen, unfortunately I am unable to connect to the API. I have it behind an Apache with jQuery and I get the messages from the chat, trying...and finally cannotn complete the request, I have checked the credentials and are ok, what can I do?

Comment: In this case, you need to ask a new question. About you question, I answered. Please follow the guide from StackOverflow, **mark** my answer if help your doubt in this Ask. And ask a new question.